# Updating Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I've been trying to make Conway's game of life using python for fun, but have run into a problem with tkinter. Essentially, I've been trying to make canvas update after every image, but I can't get it to wait long enough for me to see between updates. Here's my code (yeah, it's pretty bad and some of it is just plain useless, but try to bear with me):

```
import random
from Tkinter import *
world = []
master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=1000, height=750)
w.pack()
def find_adj(a, b):
#yeah, this is probably the single worst part of my code. 
#when declaring a class like this I do (x,y) instead of (y,x)
    adjs = 0
    if world[b][a - 1] == 1:
        adjs += 1
    if world[b][a + 1] == 1:
        adjs += 1
    if world[b - 1][a] == 1:
        adjs += 1
    if b > len(world):
        if world[b + 1][a] == 1:
            adjs += 1
    return adjs

def select(num1, num2):
    if find_adj(num1, num2) <= 1 or find_adj(num1, num2, ) == 4:
        world[num2][num1] = 0
    else:
        world[num2][num1] = 1

for n in range(0, 10):
    world.append([])
    for m in range(0, 10):
        world[n].append(random.randint(0, 1))
        if world[n][m]==1:
            w.create_rectangle(n*10, m * 10, 10 * (n + 1), 10 * (m + 1), 
fill="black")
            w.pack()#do not know what this is doing down here, I have no idea where to put it
print(world[0])
for o in range(0, 9):
    print("hello")
#w.create_rectangle(20,25,100,100, fill="black")
for y in (0, len(world) - 1):
    for x in range(0, len(world[y]) - 1):
            select(x, y)
            if world[y][x]==1:
                w = w.update_idletasks
                w.create_rectangle(y*10,x*10,10*(y+1), 10*(x+1), fill = "black")
    print(world)
mainloop()
```

How can I fix this problem (side note: if you think I'm trying to do something that I'm definitely not ready to do yet, or that my code is too much of a mess for any sane person to try to correct, just comment "give up kid" instead of downvoting it, and I'll delete the question.)

Comment: I would recommend starting with a basic program first before trying something more complex on this scale.

Comment: need read more document about of `python canvas`

Answer (score 0):

*"Don't give up kid"* ;-)

You have a problem on this line (towards the end):

`w = w.update_idletasks`

`update_idletasks` is a method, to call it on `w`, it requires double parenthesis. This method doesn't return anything (it returns `None`), so you should not assign it to `w`.

replace it with:

`w.update_idletasks()`

---

Now, to answer your question: your program is not going too fast, and preventing you from seeing what is going on... What is happening is that you have not yet coded the part where the next generation replaces the previous one.

This is what you should try to do now.

Maybe you could read a little bit about `functions`? I am sure it will be useful to finish your project.